# Paragraph style footnotes in plain XeTeX

Tags: xetex, footnotes

I’m trying to get footnotes set in the paragraph style in plain XeTeX. I’ve pasted the code from `fnpara.tex` into the preamble of my document and changed the fonts used in the actual footnotes to Palatino Linotype by pasting:

```
\font\footnumberfont="Palatino Linotype:mapping=tex-text" at 8pt

\font\footnotesize="Palatino Linotype:mapping=tex-text" at 8pt
```

after the code from `fnpara'. The main font in my document is set like this:

```
\font\pala="Palatino Linotype:+onum,mapping=tex-text" at 10pt
```

I call it by putting `\pala' at the start of the text. Everything works fine except for one thing: the superscript footnote reference numbers in the text block are in Computer Modern (cmr7), which looks strange, since everything else is in Palatino. I’m new to plain (Xe)TeX.

minimum working example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xetex

%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\input eplain

\font\pala="Palatino Linotype:+onum,mapping=tex-text" at 10pt

PLACE CODE FROM "fnpara.tex" HERE

\font\footnumberfont="Palatino Linotype:mapping=tex-text" at 8pt 
\font\footnotesize="Palatino Linotype:mapping=tex-text" at 8pt

\pala

Lorem\footnote{First footnote.} ipsum dolor sit amet,\footnote{Second footnote.
(Every once in a while a long footnote might occur, just to make things difficult.)}
consectetur adipisicing\footnote{Third footnote.} elit,

\bye
```

i put the MWE in the question; thanks Torbjørn T.

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example for your text: in particular, how are you generating your superscripts? (If you are using math mode then you'll be getting CM, whereas if you are measuring/boxing up and using text mode then it should work.)

Comment: The number in front of the actual footnote (bottom of the page) is in the correct font ?

Comment: @ ach, yes the numbers in the footnotes are in the correct font, it’s the referring numbers in the text block that are in the wrong font (Computer Modern). I want them to be in Palatino Linotype.

Comment: Rather than adding an MWE in a comment, you should edit your question and include it there.

Comment: @Terence I've formatted your code for you. To get code formatted correctly, after you paste it in, select it and click on the `{}` formatting icon.

Answer (score 6):

I think I’ve fixed it. It was a math mode problem. I got some code from
https://gist.github.com/wspr/616937

```
% set up Cambria Math as math roman, symbol and extension families
\font\1="Cambria Math:script=math" at 10pt
\font\2="Cambria Math:script=math;+ssty=0" at 7pt
\font\3="Cambria Math:script=math;+ssty=1" at 5pt
\textfont0=\1 \scriptfont0=\2 \scriptscriptfont0=\3
\textfont2=\1 \scriptfont2=\2 \scriptscriptfont2=\3
\textfont3=\1 \scriptfont3=\2 \scriptscriptfont3=\3
\let\tenrm=\1 \rm
```

and edited it down to:

```
\font\1="Palatino Linotype" at 7pt
\scriptfont0=\1
```

then I pasted this after the code from fnpara and it put my footnote superscripts into Palatino Linotype. I’m not using XeTeX to typeset mathematics, so this is all I need. I just want my superscripts not to be in Computer Modern.

Answer (score 6):

There is another (perhaps better) way of doing it. Define a font

```
\font\sups="Palatino Linotype:+sups,mapping=tex-text" at 10pt
```

then replace the line

```
$^{\the\footno}$\@sf\vfootnote}
```

of fnpara.tex with

```
{\sups\the\footno}\@sf\vfootnote}
```

Instead of using math mode to generate footnote superscripts, this method uses the OpenType ‘sups’ tag.